# UPDATE A COLUMN WITH DIFFERENT VALUES IN ROWS

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sql-update

I want to update `ColumnX` of `TableA` with the values of `ColumnY` in `TableB`.

This two tables have in common the atrribute `id`.
Is it possible, when I try an UPDATE code I get

> Subquery returns multiple rows

The subquery looks something like this:

```
UPDATE TableA 
SET ColumnX = (SELECT ColumnY FROM TableB WHERE tableA.id=tableA.id);
```

Comment: LESS ALL CAPS PLEASE, especially in the title. It's yelling.

Comment: Yes, Table A and B share an atribute but the column I want to update does have differetn column in every row

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
UPDATE TableA 

    SET ColumnX = (SELECT ColumnY FROM TableB WHERE tableA.id=tableB.id);
```

And make sure that `SELECT ColumnY FROM TableB WHERE tableA.id in (SELECT id FROM TableB )` returns 1 value

Answer (score 1):

your where clause is currently using `tableA.id=tableA.id`, which will be true for every row. Try:

```
UPDATE TableA 
SET ColumnX = (SELECT ColumnY FROM TableB WHERE tableB.id=tableA.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use joins like when you are selecting rows, for example:

```
UPDATE TableA, TableB set TableA.ColumnX=TableB.ColumnY WHERE TableA.id=TableB.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the name in your where clause condition after `=` as you have same table name resulting into multiple results to `TableB.id` or try below

```
         UPDATE TableA A
         Join TableB B
         On
         A.id= B.id
        SET A.ColumnX = B.ColumnY
```

Comment: When you say TableA A*  the A(*) what is?

Comment: That is an alias like if there is reuse of that same table in condition or select statement then if we could alias a table say A then it is easy to use rather writing whole name each time it requires

Comment: UPDATE Apartment  a
         Join Location i
         On
         Apartment.id_location= Location.id_location;
        SET Apartment.state = Location.state

Comment: Typo remove that semicolon i have uodated my answer run now